# H5BP Ant Build Script Not updating the cachebusted file names

Tags: ant, html5boilerplate

I have a H5BP (5.2.0) and Ant-build-script (1.18) which is working perfectly except for:

The published html does not update the module directory with the cache busted name; e.g.,   in source pages should be updated to  in the published pages.
This only happens with the modules dir.

Is this a known issue in build.xml, or more likely in my projects.xml setup? I don't really what in projects.xml might effect this.

A lessor issue is that module folder content is not minified, just passed through.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at that. I think you had to set up dir.js.modules in project.xml. Is that set?

Comment: dir.js.modules    = ${dir.js}/modules is set in project.xml

Comment: dir.js.modules    = ${dir.js}/modules is set in project.xml. The script does fine processing the js files. What isn't happening is updating the HTML script tags with the mangled name. Seems like the issue might be in the lines 679-683: <echo message="Update the HTML to reference our name-mangled modules directory"/>
        <replaceregexp match="&lt;script.*src=['&quot;]?${dir.js.modules}/(.*)['&quot;]\s*&gt;"
        replace="&lt;script src='${modules.js.dir}/\1'&gt;" flags="mg">
            <fileset dir="${dir.intermediate}" includes="${page-files}"/>
        </replaceregexp>.... Thanks Rob